# Shortest way to write immutable struct in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, immutability

Quite often I come across the need for small immutable data structures. Others would probably use Tuples in these cases, but I really dislike that Tuples don't read nicely and don't express that much meaning. A `Value2` of `int` doesn't tell me anything.

An example would be creating a lookup table (Dictionary) for a combination of two properties, i.e. `Name` and `Rating`.

The shortest way to make an immutable struct for these cases that I know of is this:

```
public struct Key
{
    public string   Name    { get; private set; }
    public int      Rating  { get; private set; }

    public LolCat(string name, int rating) : this()
    {
        Name    = name;
        Rating  = rating;
    }
}

// useage
var key = new Key( "MonorailCat", 5 );
```

In my opinion there is still a lot of *'syntactic fat'* in here that I would like to get rid of.
I could make it a lot more readable when I would just expose fields directly.

```
public struct Key
{
    public string   Name;
    public int      Rating;
}

// useage
var key = new Key { Name = "MonorailCat", Rating = 5 };
```

I really like the syntax of this, because there is barely any syntactic fat. The big disadvantage is of course that it is not immutable, with all it's dangers.

In the ideal case I would just like to have a special type for this, with the real bare minimum of definition, like:

```
public immutable struct Key
{
    string  Name;
    int     Rating;
}

// useage (needs compiler magic)
var key = new Key( Name: "MonorailCat", Rating: 5 );
```

**Question**

Is there a real world solution something closer to the example on the bottom, to reduce the amount of syntactic fat for a very simple immutable struct?

Comment: Why don't use a class in this case?

Comment: Why not expose the properties as `readonly` fields?  You'd at least remove the `{get; private set;}` (and you'd still need the constructor).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of C# 6, you can write fairly compact `struct` initializers:

```
public struct Key
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Rating { get; }

    public Key(string name, int rating)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Rating = rating;
    }
}
```

... which is at least *significantly* shorter. I'd strongly advise implementing `IEquatable<Key>`, mind you.

Note that as you're dealing with a struct, you'll still be able to write:

```
Key key = new Key();
Console.WriteLine(key.Rating); // 0
```

... which may not be a problem, but generally needs *considering* at least.

Before C# 6, I'd actually go even longer than your current code, in order to write the properties as read-only properties:

```
public struct Key
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly int rating;

    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    public int Rating { get { return rating; } }

    public Key(string name, int rating)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

I feel this makes it more clearly "meant to be immutable" - if you've got a writable property, even if the setter is only private, that doesn't convey the right impression IMO. (Although it's worth noting that immutability in structs is always a *little* bit of a pretense, given that you can assign to `this` in members...)

Comment: Why still using the Properties though, and not directly exposing the readonly fields like in X.L. Ants example? Just for 'meaning'?

Comment: @DirkBoer: I pretty much *never* expose fields. It feels all kinds of wrong to me :)

Comment: Got it. Just all that syntactic fat also feels so wrong to me. Maybe I have some really weird coding habits, but it seems like such a common case. And in fact, the introduction of the Tuples would suggest that it actually is a common case. With a pretty unreadable solution in my opinion. :/

Comment: Hi Jon, your suggestion for implementing `IEquatable`; is that just for performance reasons and boxing/unboxing?

Comment: @DirkBoer: Well, it's `IEquatable<T>` rather than just `IEquatable`... and yes, it's largely for performance reasons, but it also documents intent. The C# 6 feature that I wrote about didn't ship in the end, so I need to edit this...

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the shortest you can write is using readonly, which is hardly shorter than your struct using properties:

```
public struct Key
{
    public readonly string  Name;
    public readonly int     Rating;

    public Key(string name, int rating){
        Name = name;
        Rating = rating;
    }
}

var key = new Key("MonorailCat", 5);
```

Comment: While that works, it does mean exposing the *fields* rather than properties - something I'm always wary of. In particular, changing from this to the C# 6 property-based version is a breaking change.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you on that, but I don't know of any case where exposing readonly fields could cause problems (except for the breaking change you mention). Is there a case I should be aware of ?

Comment: Depending on the implementation, UI binding is often not set up for fields - and there are all kinds of places in the language where the differences between properties and fields are quite subtle. It's not *as bad* when the fields are read-only, but I'd still personally always prefer to use properties. To my mind, properties are part of the API between a type and its clients; fields are an implementation detail. (In Noda Time for example, I've recently reimplemented everything massively - the fields have changed completely, but the properties are the same as before...)

Answer (score 3):

In C# 7.2 there is a readonly struct.

```
readonly public struct ReadonlyPoint3D
{
    public ReadonlyPoint3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }
    //setters would not compile
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    public double Z { get; }

    private static ReadonlyPoint3D origin = new ReadonlyPoint3D();
    public static ref readonly ReadonlyPoint3D Origin => ref origin;
    public ReadonlyPoint3D Scale(double factor)
    {
        /* all fail compilation
        X *= factor;
        Y *= factor;
        Z *= factor;
        */
        return new ReadonlyPoint3D(X * factor, Y * factor, Z * factor);
    }
}
```

The compiler enforces that all members are readonly. 
This passed as 'in' reference rather than copy of receiver which is usually more efficient.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types)

Comment: +1, though I'd say "which is usually more efficient". There are a few times when it is less so. As a rule you can generally be happy that it's going to be more efficient most of the time, but if trying to optimise a hotspot where that hotspot uses an internal readonly struct then one of the things worth profiling is taking that readonly off.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed. Changed.

Comment: @JonHanna Can you elaborate on what you meant by internal readonly struct? I am thinking of having a class holding field that is readonly struct. I will have a very large number of instances of the class. I am hoping to improve performance by doing so.It seems that would not work?